# Programmatically check if executable exists without running it or using `which`

Tags: haskell

We can run a process `foo` with help of `System.Process.proc` as follows:

```
createProcess $ proc "foo" []
```

However we do not know ahead of time whether `foo` can be found. We could run it and catch an exception but that's poor. We could also first call out to `which` but that also sucks. In the `process` library we find [`RawCommand`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.6.1.0/docs/System-Process.html#v:RawCommand) which as of today says

> The FilePath argument names the executable, and is interpreted
>   according to the platform's standard policy for searching for
>   executables. Specifically:
>
> - on Unix systems the execvp(3) semantics is used, where if the executable filename does not contain a slash (/) then the PATH
>     environment variable is searched for the executable.
> - on Windows systems
>     the Win32 CreateProcess semantics is used. Briefly: if the filename
>     does not contain a path, then the directory containing the parent
>     executable is searched, followed by the current directory, then some
>     standard locations, and finally the current PATH. An .exe extension is
>     added if the filename does not already have an extension. For full
>     details see the documentation for the Windows SearchPath API.

This is precisely what I would like to do but there doesn't seem to be any exposed functionality that does it. Am I just missing it, is there a more canonical/better way or do I have to dig through `process` internals? The solution should be portable (Windows/Linux).

Comment: As the quote in your question clearly states, the desired semantics are implemented by the OS, so if you want to access it directly, you'll need to use the FFI (and re-write all the cross platform compatibility code yourself). "We could run it and catch an exception but that's poor" - there's nothing wrong with this approach, and it seems by far the simplest one. (If you want your program to be robust you should probably handle exceptions from external programs anyways).

Comment: If the intention is to run it anyway, I think that trying to run it and catching the exception is the *ideal* solution - you have to handle that case regardless as there's the risk of the state changing between the existence check and the execution.

Comment: Have you had a look at [shake: command](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/shake-0.16/docs/Development-Shake-Command.html)? I use it mostly as an alternative to shell scripts

Comment: @ryachza Exactly! Check if a file exists = you know it *existed* at a discrete point in time when the syscall was executed. 1us later your check is worthless in the sense you cannot take it as a given that it sill exits - your code needs to handle exceptions however you approach this.

Comment: For my use-case, the binary was expected to be on read-only file system. I was writing some executable and it allowed the user to specify the path of the command to run. I also wanted to show the "default" chosen path if the user failed to provide an explicit choice. So you're right that the check may be worthless in many scenarios but not all. Think for example about `./configure`: it finds the paths of build dependencies and ensures they are there, before it runs. Running `shoot-missiles` to check that it exists is not really acceptable in all cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you want `findExecutable` function from [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.3.1.5/docs/System-Directory.html#v:findExecutable).

```
Prelude System.Directory> findExecutable "gcc"
Just "/usr/bin/gcc"
```